# Python Pandas: Applying changes to specific columns by column names

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

So I have a [Python2.7] Pandas dataframe (df) as below:

```
        name    flag  dummy_D random ID dummy_S dummy_T 
0       Mick  Purple    2     NaN   1     21       32
1       John     Red   NaN    NaN   2    w32       4  
2  Christine     NaN    2     NaN   2    w33       3 
3     Stevie     NaN    4     NaN   2    w34       2 
4    Lindsey     NaN    5     NaN   2    w35      NaN
```

and I would like to replace all the NaN in columns stating with 'dummy' with previous values (and only these columns while the rest of the dataframe remain unchanged)

Here is what I did:

```
dummycol = [col for col in df.columns if 'dummy' in col] 

for d in dummycol:
      df[d] = df[d].fillna(method = 'pad')
```

My question is:

**Is there a better (in terms of coding and memory efficiency) way in Pandas to do this instead of wasting memory to create a list + looping through it? Would be great to have a one liner solution!**

Many Thanks in advance!

Will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way, so you can call [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) on the columns to get the cols of interest and then call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html#pandas.DataFrame.fillna) on all those columns at the same time:

```
In [152]:
cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.startswith('dummy')]
df[cols] = df[cols].fillna(method='pad')
df

Out[152]:
        name    flag  dummy_D  random  ID dummy_S  dummy_T
0       Mick  Purple        2     NaN   1      21       32
1       John     Red        2     NaN   2     w32        4
2  Christine     NaN        2     NaN   2     w33        3
3     Stevie     NaN        4     NaN   2     w34        2
4    Lindsey     NaN        5     NaN   2     w35        2
```

Answer (score 0):

This avoids your list comprehension and only loops over the columns once:

```
for d in df.columns:
    df[d] = df[d].fillna(method = 'pad') if 'dummy' in d
```

Comment: Thanks but I would prefer EdChum idea as it doesnt involve a For Statement -> One of the major result I move from Python to Pandas

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional list comprehension together with `.loc`:

```
_ = [df.loc[:, col].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True) for col in df if col[:5] == 'dummy']

>>> df
        name    flag  dummy_D  random  ID dummy_S  dummy_T
0       Mick  Purple        2     NaN   1      21       32
1       John     Red        2     NaN   2     w32        4
2  Christine     NaN        2     NaN   2     w33        3
3     Stevie     NaN        4     NaN   2     w34        2
4    Lindsey     NaN        5     NaN   2     w35        2
```

Comment: Thanks but I find EdChum idea easier to understand as I am unfamiliar with .loc . Something I wish I will get better in time!